# Is it make sense to handle websocket based on path?

Tags: websocket, dart

In `WebSocket` object, there are no getter for `Uri`, hence there are no way to know which path the object is requesting. Some idea I have is to implement the `WebSocket`, and add the `Uri` getter.

By doing that, now I have 2 ways to handle `WebSocket`: through `Url` or using `where()` to filter based on keyword I have. Which one is the preferred way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at the [*Managing WebSocket Connections* section of *Chapter 5. Walkthrough: Dartiverse Search*](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch05.html#ch05-server-web-socket). In the example the author shows how to use the [route package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/route) in front of the websocket handling. It may answer your question.